# .NET consumer of ActiveX throwing TargetParameterCountException

Tags: c#, .net, c++, com, activex

I have a .NET (3.5 w/ Dev Studio 2008) app that hosts a visual Active X (written in C++ w/ Dev Studio 2003). Have access to all sources, but can't easily move the Active X control up to 2008.

This as worked fine in the past. Made some changes to the Active X control and now, when calling one method on the Active X, I'm getting a TargetParameterCountException 100% of the time. The signature of the Active X method is:

```
LONG CMyActive::License(LPCTSTR string1, LPCTSTR string2, LONG long1, LPCTSTR string3, LPCTSTR string4);
```

When viewing the method in object browser of reflector, .NET sees it as:

```
public virtual int License(string string1, string string2, int long1, string string3, string string4)
```

I renamed the parameters for demonstration purpose (boss gets twitchy about any code). I left the method name, as it could be relevant.

There are method calls prior that work. I just can't seen to figure out why I'm all of a sudden getting this exception. The HRESULT is 0x8002000e and a quick search seems to indicate that's a general one.

Thanks to all for reading.

**Edit**

Thanks for the pointers. There is some comfort in knowing others are perplexed.  What is odd, is that this did work. This behavior cropped up after a rebuild of the Active X. No interface or other IDL changes. And it's on multiple machines, not just limited to one dev box or such.

**Edit 2**

For S&G's I added a new method,

```
LONG CMyActive::XXXLicense(LPCTSTR string1, LPCTSTR string2, LONG long1, LPCTSTR string3, LPCTSTR string4);
```

Rebuilt everything and now I can call the new method... This smells like a bug either in the compiler and/or the COM interoperability layer of .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HRESULT is `DISP_E_BADPARAMCOUNT` (better for googling than "0x8002000e").

Seems other people have bumped into this problem:

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=96353

http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?t=85215